# Multilevel and Multiple inheritance using super() in Python returns odd result

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super

if I type this this code,

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def show_letter(self):
        print("This is B")

class C(B):
    def show_letter(self):
        super().show_letter()
        print("This is C")

class E(B):
      def show_letter(self):
        super().show_letter()
        print("This is E")

class D(C, E):
    division = "North"

    def show_letter(self):
        super().show_letter()
        print("This is D")

div1 = D()
div1.show_letter()
```

it returns:

```
This is B
This is E
This is C
This is D
```

Why is there "E" printed ?
If I delete super() in C class, "E" is not printed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [the method resolution order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). The first call is in `D`, then it calls `C` due to the arguments order: `D(C, E)`. It could call `B` as parent but the latter is also a parent for `E`, so it is called the first. Only after that there is a `B` call. Thereby your call order is **D -> C -> E -> B** & the `print` order is revered.